# select the data which does not meet the requirement in R

Tags: r

Let say I have data like this.

```
    ConDate    ID    TreN  AriT
   20180424  54294631  1  8030
   20180424  54294631  2  8030
   20180425  25005102  1  8040
   20180425  25005102  2  8045
```

I want to find data which has same conDate,ID,AriT but different TreN.

In this case first and second row should be selected.

I am not sure how to write query for this kind of situation.

If they meet the requirement, then I want to add extra column next to 'AriT' saying Y for meet the requirement and N for Not meet the requirement.

can some one please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(ConDate, ID, AriT) %>%
  mutate(new_col = n_distinct(TreN) > 1)
`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this using `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::filter`?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ConDate, ID, AriT) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(TreN) > 1)
## A tibble: 2 x 4
## Groups:   ConDate, ID, AriT [1]
#   ConDate       ID  TreN  AriT
#     <int>    <int> <int> <int>
#1 20180424 54294631     1  8030
#2 20180424 54294631     2  8030
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "   ConDate    ID    TreN  AriT
   20180424  54294631  1  8030
   20180424  54294631  2  8030
   20180425  25005102  1  8040
   20180425  25005102  2  8045", header = T)
```

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, I think you're right. Thanks, I made an edit.

Comment: @RonakShah Ah just saw your comment at the top. If you want to post as independent answer I'll remove my edit.

Comment: No, it's fine. You had got it right anyway. OP wants a new column though with "Y" and "N" instead of filtering the rows.